# Swapping values around in a list and recording original index

Tags: python, python-3.x

Preface: This is a homework assignment and I am not looking for a complete answer, just a little nudge in the right direction.  I am writing a simple encryption program, that will take the name of an file as input, open it and rewrite it with the lines randomly shifted around.  I have done this, but I need to somehow keep track of the line numbers that were shifted around.  I know I need to write a new list and append the indexes+1 when they changed, but I can't quite figure out where to put it.

```
from random import *
seed(123)

text_file = input("Enter a name of a text file to mix: ")
f = open(text_file, 'r')
encrypted = open('encrypted.txt', 'w')
index = open('index.txt', 'w')
lines = []
for line in f:
    line = line.strip('\n')
    lines.append(line) 
ll=len(lines)
new_dict = {}
for line in lines:
    new_dict[lines.index(line)+1] = line
for i in range (0,ll*3):
    random_one = randint(0,ll-1)
    random_two = randint(0,ll-1)
    temp1 = lines[random_one]
    temp2 = lines[random_two]
    lines[random_one] = temp2
    lines[random_two] = temp1
for line in lines:
    encrypted.write(line + "\n")
encrypted.close()
```

As you can see I have also made a dictionary that would contain the contents of the .txt file as 1:lineone 2:linetwo.  But I am not sure if it would be easier to use this, or just use a list to keep track of it.

Edit: I have changed my code to include:

```
new_dict[random_one] = temp2
new_dict[random_two] = temp1
```

new_dict now prints the correct order of the shifted list, but at the wrong indexes.  For example, 1:line7 2:line11, but I want the indexes to match the line number so I can just print off the keys into an index file to use for decrypting. ex: 7:line7 11:line11 Any tips?

Comment: You may be interested in using a shuffling algorithm to reduce the amount of bookkeeping you're currently doing. You will find that the [Knuth implementation of the Fisher-Yates algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher–Yates_shuffle#The_modern_algorithm) probably suits your needs.

Comment: If ```new_dict``` contains the information you need to reconstruct the file and  you have implemented it correctly (it works) then at this point it is the easiest because it is done.

Comment: You might find [enumerate](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#enumerate) useful for constructing ```new_dict``` : ```for i, line in enumerate(lines): ...```

Comment: What wwii said. Doing `for line in lines: new_dict[lines.index(line)+1] = line` is _very_ inefficient. For each line it has to do a linear scan through the `lines` list to find the index of the first line that matches the current `line`.

Answer (score 1):

You don't actually need to save the order of the shuffled lines. You can simply re-create it when you need it by using the same random seed that you originally used. The code below should give you a few ideas.

```
import random

random.seed(123)

# Create a simple list of strings
a = list('abcdefgh')
print(a)

# Generate a shuffled list of indices
indices = list(range(len(a)))
random.shuffle(indices)

# Shuffle a into b
b = []
for i in indices:
    b.append(a[i])
print(b)

# Unshuffle b into c
c = [None] * len(b)
for i, v in zip(indices, b):
    c[i] = v
print(c)
```

**output**

```
['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h']
['b', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'd', 'h', 'c', 'a']
['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h']
```

Answer (score 0):

Just shuffle an numpy array with indeces and shuffle them. So you can save the indices for later.

```
import numpy as np

indices = np.arange(5)
np.random.shuffle(indices)
print(indices)
```

Version without numpy:

```
from random import shuffle
indices = list(range(5))
shuffle(indices)
```

Comment: You can do that with a plain list. Why bring Numpy into this? Besides, this is a homework assignment, and the OP probably isn't permitted to use Numpy.

Comment: numpy and pandas have become the overkill solution of choice it seems. Why is numpy needed here?

Comment: I added the list solution. Thank you guys.

Comment: You should just do `list(range(10))`. `range(10)` gives you an iterator that *is* a list of items from 0 - 9. So, to put the *list* in memory, just call `list` on it.